# Print in external files with FOR and getting blank txt files

Tags: python, file

In that part of code I make the files txt and its working

```
import sys
for i in range(6):
   file = open('teste{:d}.txt'.format(i), 'a')
    sys.stdout = file
```

And now the problem, the files were created but in this part of code it didnt work, i can compile but the files are empty

```
 for i in range(1,6):
    f=open('100K_Array_{:d}.txt'.format(i), 'r')
    alist = f.readlines()
    quickSort(alist)
    print(alist)

 f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please remove the irrelevant code (such as the sort) and provide cut-and-paste code to illustrate the problem.  Among other things, your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Correct indentation is crucial for Python.

Comment: `file.close()` should be `f.close()`.

Comment: You're creating files named `teste#.txt`, but you're reading files named `100K_Array_#.txt`.

Comment: Yes, Im reading the second file to sort it and then creating a file with it sorted

Comment: Check the path, then check if the file is being created as expected. Then check the filenames of the files you are reading. Use f.close() within the loop (i.e. indent it properly as suggested by Prune).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you haven't closed your output file properly. You should either use

```
with open('teste{:d}.txt', 'a') as file:
...
```

in which case `with` statement will handle closing the file for you. Otherwise you need to add `file.close()` to your current code.